# Using Mysql C API for c++ codes

Tags: c++, mysql, c, database, api

I'm writing a c++ connector to a mysql datdabase and the only thing that I have is mysql.com references and everything here is for C and I wanted to see if it's ok to use this API for c++ codes or not?
for example for the affected row we have

```
 char *stmt = "UPDATE products SET cost=cost*1.25
              WHERE group=10";
mysql_query(&mysql,stmt);
printf("%ld products updated",
       (long) mysql_affected_rows(&mysql));
```

and is it same for cpp?

And I'm talking about this because we have somthing like this for c++ but not for C:

```
sql::ResultSet  *res;
while(res->next()){
        columnNames[i-1] = res->getString(i);
        i++;
    }
```

note that this just a part of a code

Comment: C++ can call any C function (provided it has been declared `extern "C"` which most libraries does these days).

Comment: The data from `res->getString()` needs the correct lifespan and type.  mysql does not understand `std::string` but otherwise it should work.

Comment: Thanks for ur attention.Actually I'm using this [dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/] for coding all the database module and actually I'm forced to use this. I wanted to know if you have any information about this and if I'm permitted to use these function [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-functions.html] instead of what is told in the c++ part [dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/] and why even there is this different? aren't they supposed be same? I mean c++ and c @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any C library can be used in C++ code. Just like [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) has mentioned in the comment.

this is just a code snippet from one of my project. I think you are looking for something like this.

```
MYSQL_ROW row;

  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
  { 
      for(int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++) 
      { 
        // printf("%s \n", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
         char* new = malloc(100);
         prtid[a]= new;
         strcpy(prtid[a],row[i]);

      } 
      a++;

  }
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/udakarajd/GenMRP_Phase2/blob/master/project_in_c/7th%20sem%20unchanged/mysql_head.h), If you want to study more

Comment: Thanks for ur attention.Actually I'm using this [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/] for coding all the database module and actually I'm forced to use this. I wanted to know if you have any information about this and if I'm permitted to use these function [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/c-api-functions.html] instead of what is told in the c++ part  [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/]  and why even there is this different? aren't they supposed be same? I mean c++ and c
@udakarajd

Comment: As to my knowledge, c and c++ are two separate languages. But we have the luxury of using c libraries in c++ since c++ is built based on c. but you will have to use C syntax.